# Windows 10 with two different physical screens; can I have settings per screen?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution, virtual-desktop

I have a laptop with full HD (FHD) display and an external monitor connected via a docking station.
It's running Windows 10.
Unfortunately I'm having some problems with the screen and some questions:

Until recently I had connected an older screen 22" that had less than FHD resolution (WSXGA I guess).
I did not configure a lot, but mainly used it for remote desktop display, realizing that the fonts in some applications looked rather blurred.
At that time I guessed it's due to the RDP compression.

Recently I got a 27" 2K screen that has a much higher resolution.
Initially Windows did just mirror the laptop display on the screen, but I didn't want that, so I tried to configure it, and that's when the problems started:

- When opening the screen settings, I can select a screen, and below are settings, so I thought that should be fine.
  However when I try to scale the large screen to 100% and the laptop's display to 125%, I realized that there is *only one* setting that applies to all screens!
  (However the native resolution is still *per screen*)
- Now the remote desktop on the large screen is "crispy", while the laptop's display looks somewhat blurred, even when not using RDP.
  So I guess that Windows internally scales all the graphics data for the big screen, and then down-samples the data when displayed on the smaller screen (Obviously to avoid issues when a program is dragged from one screen to another (it would have to handle the resolution switch during dragging otherwise)).
  Is that correct?
- When using virtual desktops, I realized that they do not work as expected (by me):
  When I have a second virtual desktop defined, and I'm working with an app that has the input focus on the laptop display, then when switching virtual desktops via hotkey, Windows also switches the virtual desktop on the second screen!
  Isn't it possible to have a virtual desktop per physical screen, or is the concept that all the screens should be placed to form tiles of a big screen?
  (Currently that's not quite the case here)

I see the individual hardware screens more as "working areas" rather than "physical extensions for the standard screen", so I'd prefer to have logical screens (i.e.: virtual desktops) per physical screen, not globally...

## Updates

### Scaling

When I had an RDP app open on the external screen, I minimized it, and I was able to set the scaling to 125% on the laptop screen.

Comment: SysInternals [Desktops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/desktops) will create genuine virtual desktops running within their own Windows Shell, but if enabled it disables the virtual desktops native to Windows. I'm also unsure how this works with extending the desktop between two or more screens.

Comment: I believe you should be able to set the scaling on the two screens independantly, in fact I've seen it done on a customers setup recently, large external monitor at 100% and laptop was at either 125% or 150%. So unless it's a limitation of your specific graphics card, perhaps you need a different/updated graphics driver?

Comment: @KeithLangmead Very odd: When I tried today, I could scale the laptop independently from the external monitor. Sometimes Windows behaves oddly.